# Is this router/provider that blocks or does not support GRE protocol?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I am currently living in dorm and I have troubles accessing company's VPN. 
I wanted to make sure that problem lies not on my side before I go to ITS and start complaining.

When I use WiFi I have no problem connecting to VPN but when it comes to cable connection, I'm always getting timeout.

I have TWO methods of connecting to company's VPN. One is through PPTP or Cisco AnyConnect.
Both methods work on WiFi, none on cable connection and I was wondering whether problem might lie on my cable connection settings.

This is what I get when I'm trying to connect using PPTP on *cable*
img: http://cap.ring0.cc/cec318ea765ce9ecff12328abd257c66.png

This is what I get when I'm connecting to PPTP on *wifi* (successfully)
img http://cap.ring0.cc/db170827280269f5ac19d46d1aed54be.png

As for anyconnect there's lot of exchange between me and the server and eventually I'm getting generic error.

Thanks